# jquery rename content insite a tag and confirming it

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

- How can I target only one container?
- The User should be able to change the Name and then confirm the change.

My function works fine but when I have more containers repeated and I confirm Its changing all the tags!

Please check the demo where you can also see the changeElementTypefunction

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/26qNq/1/

JS:

```
$('.replace').on('click', function (){
    $("h2").changeElementType("textarea");
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next('a').show();

    $('.confirm').on('click', function(){
        var $textarea = $('textarea');
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).prev('a').show();
        $textarea.html($textarea.val()).changeElementType("h2");
    });


    if ($('textarea:visible')){
         $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                alert('You pressed enter!');
                $("textarea").changeElementType("h2");
                $('.replace').css('opacity','1');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the relevant `h2`/`textarea`

```
var container = $(this).closest('.rename')
container.find('h2').changeElementType("textarea");
```

and

```
var container = $(this).closest('.rename')
var $textarea = container.find('textarea');
```

You also should nest your handler binding because each time your try to edit, you add a new handler

---

Full changes

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if ($('textarea:visible')) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            alert('You pressed enter!');
            $("textarea").changeElementType("h2");
            $('.replace').css('opacity', '1');
        }
    }
});

$('.replace').on('click', function () {
    var container = $(this).closest('.rename')
    container.find('h2').changeElementType("textarea");
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next('a').show();
});

$('.confirm').on('click', function () {
    var container = $(this).closest('.rename')
    var $textarea = container.find('textarea');

    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev('a').show();
    $textarea.html($textarea.val()).changeElementType("h2");
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/26qNq/6/

Comment: thanks dude! do you think the keypress could work in the same way too?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an ID to each of them seems to work.

All I needed to do was add a numeric ID to each element we were using and add this to your replace code:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$("h2#" + id).changeElementType("textarea");
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/26qNq/12/